# Lucene for Blackberry OS?

Tags: blackberry, lucene

Does anyone know if and where I can get a port of Lucene or a similar library that allows full text searching on Blackberry?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is no - there is no way to get lucene on blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get an older version of lucene running. This user reported success:
http://archives.devshed.com/forums/java-118/mobile-lucene-918481.html

Answer (score -1):

CLucene can do that. CLucene is a pure, cross-platform, C++ port of Lucene, currently in the process of conforming to Lucene 2.3.2. It executes faster, and works lighter. Definitely suitable also for Blackberry applications. See:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene

http://clucene.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=clucene/clucene;a=summary

Comment: I wouldn't know, never tried it myself, but figured C++ can run on anything. If it can't run as-is on blackberry, I'm sure a Java wrapper is a good way to go.